# Count consecutive null rows from a joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following tables:

```
members:
----------------------------------------------
| member_id | member_name | member_join_date |
----------------------------------------------  

events:
-------------------------
| event_id | event_name |
-------------------------

event_dates:
--------------------------------------
| event_id | event_date | event_week |
--------------------------------------

attendance:
------------------------------------------------------------
| member_id | event_id | attendance_date | attendance_week |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I have members who joined the organization at a certain time and they may attend weekly events (the occurrences of which are monitored by the `event_dates` table)

What I want to do is get all members that have at least 3-consecutive absences

I did all I could and I think I have each part of the query but don't know how to merge them together.

Get all events that they could've attended:

```
    SELECT
      m.member_id AS id,
      ed.event_id,
      ed.event_week
    FROM
      members AS m
      LEFT JOIN
        event_dates AS ed
        ON
          ed.event_date >= m.member_join_date
```

Get all the events they actually attended:

```
    SELECT
      m.member_id AS id,
      a.event_id
    FROM
      members AS m
      LEFT JOIN
        attendance AS a
        ON
          a.member_id = m.member_id
```

And probably the answer to this question if I manage to merge the two queries into one:

[Count of consecutive not null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321670/count-of-consecutive-not-null-values)

But this time I want to count `NULL` values

Answer (score 0):

You could try below:

```
select * from (select m.*,k.*, 
@rn := CASE WHEN bevent_id is null THEN @rn+1 ELSE 0 END AS rn
        from(
SELECT
      m.member_id AS id,
      ed.event_id  ,event_date  
    FROM
      members AS m
       left JOIN
        event_dates AS ed
        ON
          ed.event_date >= m.member_join_date) m
left join (SELECT
      m.member_id AS bid,
      a.event_id as bevent_id
    FROM
      members AS m
      LEFT JOIN
        attendance AS a
        ON
          a.member_id = m.member_id) k  on m.id=k.bid 
and m.event_id=k.bevent_id , (SELECT  @rn := 0) AS vars
order by m.id,m.event_date ) main
where rn>=3
```

Using the two query you provided, i do a left join to compare the result of the two query.
In order to track if the member absence for 3 consecutive events, i use @rn to track.

[SQL FIDDLE here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f73ad/35)